# abrir archivos netcdf en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, librería, netcdf4

Quiero abrir un archivo .nc en python pero me aparece el siguiente problema, el cual no entiendo que significa.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset

rootgrp = Dataset("cdd_ACCESS1-3_OND_1979-2005_2.5bilineal.nc", format="NETCDF4")

print (rootgrp.data_model)
```

Y obtengo:

> In [6]:  from netCDF4 import Dataset    ...: rootgrp =
>   Dataset("cdd_ACCESS1-3_OND_1979-2005_2.5bilineal.nc",
>   format="NETCDF4")    ...: print (rootgrp.data_model)
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       from netCDF4 import Dataset
>
> File "/home/florencia/.ipython/netCDF4/**init**.py", line 3, in
>   
>       from ._netCDF4 import *
>
> ImportError: /home/florencia/.ipython/netCDF4/_netCDF4.so: undefined
>   symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct

Qué significa? Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: intenta primero abrirlo con vi y darle :set ff=unix y lo guardas para eliminar cualquier caracter raro si no intenta con esto:  pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall netCDF4

Comment: @Bryro recién estoy empezando a usar python, por lo cual no sé que es  'vi'  :/ qué es?

Comment: puedes ver esto: [editor vi](https://es.ccm.net/contents/318-linux-el-editor-de-vi) para que aprendeas acerca de el...

Comment: Ok, ahí leí el link que me pasaste. Tu recomendación inicial es que abra el archivo cdd_ACCESS... y le agregue :set ff=unix , o a qué archivo debería agregarle esa sentencia?

Comment: A su vez, intenté con : pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall netCDF4 , pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema

Comment: Florencia, pareciera que hay una inconsistencia entre la versión de Python (3x) y la versión con la que fue compilado el paquete netCDF4 (2x).

Comment: Hola @PatricioMoracho, cómo puedo solucionarlo entonces?

Comment: Revisa el procedimiento de instalación de `python`, `ipython` y `netCDF4` revisa que cada uno tengan versiones consistentes, mucho más no puedo decirte por que necesitaría estar físicamente en tu lugar para podar darte una idea más precisa.

Comment: Hay que seguir los pasos que proponen en el enlace oficial  https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf4-python